# Why does the Aether require a host, when it's the MCU Reality Stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world, infinity-stones

The whole "bonding with a person" gimmick is more in line with the Soul Stone, not the Reality Stone. So why does the [Aether](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Aether) have that certain characteristic? In fact, why does it empower the user at all?

The key question is: Why does the Reality Stone require a host?

Comment: What if Aether is soul stone too..

Comment: @ILoveYou No, it has been confirmed by Marvel that it is the Reality Stone. It cannot be two things at once. Sorry.

Comment: `It cannot be two things at once.` ~> Any citation?

Comment: There are 6 Infinity Stones. If it was both, than it would only be 5.

Comment: There are 6 Infinity Stones. It doesn't mean there needs to be 6 containers...

Comment: The Soul Stone is orange in the MCU. The Aether is red. Stop denying basic facts for the last time. -_-

Comment: `The Soul Stone is orange in the MCU.` ~> Any credible citation?

Comment: I'm looking for a citation but I'm pretty sure Feige has claimed that we haven't seen the Soul Stone yet but we would see it in Phase 3. That rules out it being the Aether, which showed up in Phase 2.

Comment: @ILoveYou I think Guardians of the Galaxy is a pretty reliable source. It was blatantly shown *on-screen* to the audience that the Soul Stone is orange. All the other colors were taken.

Comment: @ILoveYou Now stop asking rhetorial questions and constantly doubting every word I say. Your entire argument can be debunked with basic evidence and common sense.

Comment: @DestinyDarren lets try to keep the comments civil.

Comment: @KutuluMike I'm being civil. Nothing wrong with a bit of snarkiness ;)

Comment: @DestinyDarren When exactly did you see soul gem in Guardians of the Galaxy?

Comment: @KutuluMike Yeah. That makes sense. Phase 3.

Comment: @ILoveYou in GotG, The Collector shows a "video" to Quill/Gamora that shows all 6 Infinity Stones on it, and the only one we haven't seen is the Orange one. Color alone doesn't really prove anything though -- the Mind Stone is yellow but Loki's Staff (it's container) was blue.

Comment: @ILoveYou Right, except Thor's vision in Age of Ultron showed us that the Reality Stone is also red when it's solidified as well. So both the container *and* the stone itself are red. Color alone *does* prove things when you combine it with common sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to distinguish between the Infinity Stones, and the *containers* for the Infinity Stones. The Stones are too powerful for most mortal beings to hold, let alone use. In the MCU, this has led to people building "artifacts" around the Stones, which appears to let someone channel the Stone's power in a specific way. For example:

- Loki's staff contained the Mind Stone.
- The Tesseract Cube contains the Space Stone
- The Orb containes the Power Stone.
- The Eye of Agamatto contains the Time Stone.

Presumably, then, the Aether was merely the *container* for the Reality Stone. As the Stones are all-powerful, there's no reason to believe their containers can't take on whatever form they want, including the form of a gas/mist-like material. It's one of the properties of *that container* that it needs a host in order to access the power of the Stone *inside it*. Presumably, before the Reality Stone can be slotted into the Infinity Gauntlet, someone will need to get it back out of the Aether.

Comment: Power stone could also bind with "hosts", so I believe it's a normal thing...

Comment: @ILoveYou Not in the MCU it hasn't. The Power Stone was only ever used inside the Cosmi-Rod, and that is not a living "host". http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmi-Rod

Comment: @DestinyDarren Did you watch the last scene of Guardians of the Galaxy in which Starlord and his friends possessed the power stone?

Comment: I think there's a difference between the Aether completely "binding" to it's host, vs. someone "wielding" the Power Stone.

Comment: Thank you, KutuluMike. That's exactly what I'm saying. The Aether *requires* a host, but the Power Stone is merely optional.

Comment: To play devil's advocate -- all of the containers listed in this response were created by livings beings other than the stone itself.. there's zero evidence of the Reality Stone having a container. In fact, the very fact that it's a free floating, viscous liquid that can basically disintegrate but still come back together (e.g., when Thor tried destroying it) would be most indicative of *no* container.. as we've seen many times throughout the MCU films, these containers can be broken. So, what about the Reality Stone? Wouldn't it of at least changed behavior if it's container broke?